# How to deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft Deserialize C#

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON file and want to assign to object ScanResult. `var text` showing all the values but scanresult showing null some null values.  https://gyazo.com/ff2ce386f845394c458a88d43a1f30d8

please suggest if I am missing something.
//MY jSon File SCAN Test 1-1543045410222.json 's code

```
{
    "at": 1543045410222,
    "i": 1000,
    "s": {
        "Sensor1": ["OFF"],
        "Sensor2": ["OFF"],
        "DataReady1": ["OFF"],
        "DataReady2": ["OFF"],
        "CV1": [5.0],
        "CV2": [6.0]
    }
}




 //ViewModel Code is as below:

public void ResendScanResult()
    {
        var ScanActivities = scanActivityManager.GetAll();
        foreach (var item in ScanActivities)
        {
            var scanName = item.ScanName;
            var dir = _dataFilePath + scanName + "\\";
            var jsonFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-{2}.json", dir, scanName, item.ScanDateEpoch);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(jsonFileName);
            // ScanResult scanResult = new ScanResult();
            var text = File.ReadAllText(jsonFileName);
            //var scanResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScanResult>(text);
            Common.Model.ScanResult scanResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Common.Model.ScanResult>(text);


            var Mvm = MonitorViewModel.Instance;
            //  TargetProvider target = Mvm.GetTargetProvider(scanResult);
            //  Mvm.PublishToServer(target, scanResult);
        }
    }
```

and my scanRescult class code is as below :

```
namespace ABX.Common.Model
{
    public class ScanResult
    {
        public ScanResult()
        {
            At = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            Interval = 1;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long At { get; set; }
        public long Interval { get; set; }
        public JObject Values { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public JObject ToJson()
        {
            JObject json = new JObject
            {
                { "at", At },
                { "i", Interval },
                { "s", Values }
            };
            return json;
        }
```

Comment: Please post the content of `jsonFileName`

Comment: @JonathanWilson I posted Full method please look into the code. I am getting all values in 'text'

Comment: @John I added JSON Files code also.

Comment: @SandyN I finally realised that - it wasn't very clear what changes your edit had made because it was a single line. My apologies.

Comment: Why do you expect those values to not be null? You have two fields that match your JSON: `At` and `Interval`. Your JSON file has an extra field `S`, which your C# class does not have. Likewise your C# class has `Name`, `Values`, and `FileName`, which your JSON does not have.

Comment: `FileName`, `Values`, and `Name` turn up null because they do not appear in your JSON file.

Comment: @John what changes and where those changes are needed to get values? please suggest.

Comment: @SandyN well your C# class should match the JSON you're trying to deserialize. If your JSON has a property "Test", then your C# class should have a corresponding property "Test". You've already managed it with "At". `JObject` should work for "s", but your current `JObject` property is called "Values" instead of "S".

Comment: @JonathanWilson I want only values `{ "at", At },
                { "i", Interval },
                { "s", Values } ` which are available in JSON File. but scanResult  Class getting and showing value from constructor only.

Comment: @John actually `Interval` is getting its value from the default constructor! Only `At` is deserializing

Comment: @Jonathan Ah - right you are.

Comment: @SandyN Either rename your class properties to match your JSON, rename your JSON to match your class properties, or implement a custom JsonConverter, where you can implement arbitrary mapping.

Comment: @JonathanWilson Thanky you guys.  You solved the Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either rename your class properties to match your JSON, rename your JSON to match your class properties, or implement a custom JsonConverter, where you can implement arbitrary mapping.